# How to "SaveAs" a specific range with VBA Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a query in my sheet. I need to export the query range into a new .xlsx workbook to a variable folder (SaveAs).

How can I SaveAs a specific range?

I tried the `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)`, which does save the entire workbook, but I just want to save a specific range of the workbook.

```
Sub SaveAsDialog()

On Error Resume Next

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
    If .Show = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    .Execute
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Copy that range to a new sheet/workbook and then save?

Answer (score 1):

**You are looking for something like this:**

- Copy and paste the data in a new Workbook and Save it

---

```
Sub SaveAsDialog()

Dim od As Workbook, nod As Workbook
Set od = ThisWorkbook

'Copy data that you want to save
od.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B10").Copy


' Add a new workbook
Set nod = Workbooks.Add

nod.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


'Save the new workbook
nod.SaveAs od.Path & "\New_Book.xlsx"
nod.Close True

End Sub
```